# Ping Works But Telnet Connection Fails - VPN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, ping, telnet

My laptop is connected to VPN and this VPN created a new adapted with new IPv4 assigned. I'm accessing a specific server through VPN and I want to run an application on my laptop and I need it to be reachable from the server so I tried to simulate the below:

- Ping from the server to my laptop can be achieved if and only if I disabled the firewall on all profiles (private, domain, public).
- When ping works from the server to my laptop VPN private IP, I cannot telnet a port from the server to my laptop it ends up with connection fails error.

My laptop is windows 11 and the server is windows server 2016

Do anyone have an idea on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: @harrymc thank you I corrected it.

Comment: Where are located the server and client (home, internet...) ? Is there a router in the middle? What is the VPN?

Comment: What makes you think your laptop would respond to a telnet request? Have you installed a telnet server application?

Comment: Telnet server is no longer a feature on Windows 11 and it should respond to telnet as long as there is an application running on this port and no firewall exists